Why can my whatsapp profile picture be seen by contacts whom ive excluded on my privacy settings?
I have set my WhatsApp profile photo in privacy settings so that only 10 contacts can see my profile picture. I have asked a few contacts who have been restricted, if they can see my profile picture and they have said yes. This is true as I can see that they can see it when they showed it to me on their phone. Why can my WhatsApp profile picture be seen by contacts whom I've excluded on my privacy settings?

Probably because they were your contacts before you changed the setting.  They already have your picture downloaded and attached to your contact record.
The setting works fine for me for new contacts.
